VBA Coloring Bar Charts Based on Cell Color - multiple bars
Can someone help to check why cell color is not applying to all bars? I am including 2 months data in the chart, but color is applying only for one month, not both
I am expecting the cell color to a apply on both bars. Below is the code which I have copied from an
answer.

Sub ColorAnItem()

    Dim i As Long, rng As Range, chrt As Chart
    
    Set chrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B27")
    
    For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
        
        chrt.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                    rng.Cells(i).Interior.Color
        
    Next i

End Sub


Your data table is "raw" and your chart is summarized, so there's not a 1:1 mapping from one cell in B2:B27 to the bars on the chart

Your data table is "raw" and your chart is summarized, so there's not a 1:1 mapping from one cell in B2:B27 to the bars on the chart.
You need to loop over the points in each series on the chart, get its category/class, and then find the same value in the raw data table and copy that cell's fill color.
Sub Tester()
    Dim cht As Chart, ser As Series, pt As Point, i As Long, x
    Dim rngLabels As Range, m As Variant
    
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Set rngLabels = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C21") 'raw data x values
    
    'check each chart series
    For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection
        'loop over the series points
        For i = 1 To ser.Points.Count
            x = ser.XValues(i) 'get the x value (category)
            m = Application.Match(x, rngLabels, 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                'if got a match, copy the cell fill color
                ser.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                    rngLabels.Cells(m).Interior.Color
            End If
        Next i
    Next ser
End Sub

My test data and chart:

Note: if you do this then there's nothing to help the user distinguish  one month from another (the legend also is unaffected and has the "old" colors)

Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.
